# Mass load of scripts using Laravel Queue and loading indicator

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, queue, laravel-5

I have been looking around for hours and days on google, but not sure if I am informed well.

So, building a website with facebook integration, once the user is logged in, a lot of data will be loaded temporary in the database, calculations will be done, exported to cashing files and deleted again in the database.

I did this first in one script, what ran for a few minutes.. not that interesting to just show "loading.." and later a timeout because the php script was running to long.

So I tried to implement ajax by:

- split up the script in parts
- the "loading" window opened and fires all ajax request
- the loading bar increases for every finished ajax call/script

=>The problem here is that some scripts crashed, because of the giant loading at once.

Because I am creating everything in laravel, someone told me to check Queue.

The situation I want to create is to add parts of this huge PHP script in a waiting line, and fire each script seperatly (or 3 at the same time). I seen that queue can be done using the database, what is perfect for me. But I only see and read about mailing queues, never see something like a waiting line for php scripts.

Meanwhile I was thinking about the perfect situation to update a loading indicator, is it best to run an ajax request to listen each second for loaded scripts? Also seen about "push technology", what is one gray bubble for me, so not sure what to implement.

Regarding Queue, I only saw examples of sending mails. I am wondering if anyone can tell me or link me to some good tutorials to integrate:

- mass loading of 30-50 php scripts
- best practice to create a loading screen, where I use bootstrap AdminLTE as layout.

once created, I am thinking of making some tutorial for this.

thank you

Comment: Have you tried to delay in ajax request by few seconds? or possible its script been crashed due to memory exceed?

Comment: I have been thinking about the delay part, but dont know how long each script runs. I am going to try to run each ajax request in serial. Perhaps that is the current solution

Comment: well technically script stop executing when you get response in ajax. but its better to give some breathing room to execute next task but not necessarily